# Declaring function using function in F#

Tags: ocaml

I'm trying to understand the following code to declare a function:

```
let string_of_int = function
    | 0 -> "zero"
    | 1 -> "one"
    | 2 -> "two"
    | _ -> "many"
```

which is the same as

```
let string_of_int2 x = match x with
    |0 -> "zero"
    |1 -> "one"
    | 2-> "two"
    _ -> "many
```

I understand The second way of declaring the function with is trying to match the input x with several possibilities that it could be. But I don't understand the first way to do it. What does function keyword do?

Also, 
what does 'a'..'z' do in the following code?

```
let is_capital = function
    | 'a'..'z' -> false
    | 'A'..'Z' -> true
    |_  -> failwith "Not a valid letter"
```

Why can't I have a function like this:

```
let examplefunc = function
    |"string"-> Printf.printf "a string"
    |3 -> Printf.print "an integer"
    |true-> Printf.printf "a boolean"
    |- -> Printf.printf "whatever"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `function` keyword is a variant of `fun` that takes in account that the behavior of the function often directly depends on the value of the argument. For instance, if we start with the following definition of the factorial function:

```
 For a positive integer n, n! is 1 if n = 0, and n * (n-1)! otherwise
```

then the natural translation to OCaml is

```
let factorial = function
| 0 (* if n = 0 *) -> 1
| n (* otherwise *) -> n * factorial (n-1)
```

like you said this strictly equivalent to

```
let factorial = fun n -> match n with
| 0 (* if n = 0 *) -> 1
| n (* otherwise *) -> n * factorial (n-1)
```

but when the argument of the function is immediately deconstructed in a pattern matching, it may be more readable to use `function` directly.

Concerning `'0'..'9'`, those are range pattern that matches all characters (i.e `'0'|'1'|'2'|'3'|'4'|..| '9'` between the lower and upper bounds (included) of the range (following the ascii ordering of characters)

```
  let is_digit = function '0'..'9' -> true | _ -> false
  is_digit '0' (* returns true *);;
  is_digit 'a' (* returns false *);;
```

Comment: Thanks, also does that mean 'a'..'z' is not a type? Because when I wrote 'a'..'z' in tryOCaml, it says syntax error.

Comment: It is a pattern not an expression indeed. This means it can be used when matching a value either inside a match `match x with | pattern -> ... `, or when binding a value in `let '0' .. '9' = '1'` (range pattern are not really useful in this context) .